# Como salvar RadioButton no Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Como eu faço para salvar apenas o RadioButton marcado? Imagens abaixo do que eu fiz. Ele está salvando um valor, mesmo eu tendo marcado o outro.No meu Banco de dados eu tenho que criar um único campo para salvar qualquer uma das informações?

Obs.: Estou usando Visual Studio(C#) e SQL Developer (Oracle)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código do banco:

```
create table Mesa
(
  cod number(5)not null,
  nome VARCHAR2(20)not null,
  ativa VARCHAR2(20)not null,
  inativa VARCHAR2(20)not null,
  Ativo number(03)not null,
  constraint PK_cod_Mesa PRIMARY KEY(cod)
);
```

C#:

```
public void Gravar()
{
    string strQuery;
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO Mesa";
    strQuery += (" VALUES(");
    strQuery += ("seq_mesa.NEXTVAL,");
    strQuery += ("'" + _nome + "',");
    strQuery += ("'" + _ativa + "',"); //campo onde irei salvar o ativa ou inativa
    strQuery += ("'1'");
    strQuery += (")");

    clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
    ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
}
```

eu declarei elas em cima desse jeito:

```
public string ativa
{
    get { return _ativa; }
    set { _ativa = value; }
}

public string inativa
{
    get { return _inativa; }
    set { _inativa = value; }
}
```

Comment: Jovem, em algum local você **atribui algum valor pra essa propriedade (`_ativa`)?**

Comment: O RadionButton vc inseriu como objetos individuais ou é um grupo - RadioButtonList?

Comment: Já resolvi.Vlw.

Answer (score 0):

classe: 
c#

class clnCadastro {

private int _cod;

```
    public int Cod
    {
        get { return _cod; }
        set { _cod = value; }
    }

    private string _nome;

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        set { _nome = value; }
    }

    private int _ativo;

    public int Ativo // receberá 0 para inativo ou 1 para ativo
    {
        get { return _ativo; }
        set { _ativo = value; }
    }
}
```

public DataSet PreencherAtivo() //para comboBox
        {
            string strQuery;
            strQuery = "Select cod_ativo From T_Ativo";
            cldBancoDeDados objBancoDados = new cldBancoDeDados();
            return objBancoDados.RetornaDataSet(strQuery);

```
    }
```

public OracleDataReader PreencherAtivoComReader(string strNome) //para radioButton
        {
            string strQuery;
            strQuery = "Select t_a.descricao 
From T_Ativo t_a inner join mesa t_m 
on t_a.cod_ativo = t_m.Ativo" 
where t_m.nome='strNome';
            cldBancoDeDados objBancoDados = new cldBancoDeDados();
            return objBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
}

public void Gravar()
{
    string strQuery;
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO Mesa";
    strQuery += (" VALUES(");
    strQuery += ("seq_mesa.NEXTVAL,");
    strQuery += ("'" + _nome + "',");
    strQuery += ("'" + _ativo + "',"); //campo onde irei salvar o ativa ou inativa
    strQuery += (")");

```
clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
```

}

c#

private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clnCadastro cadastro = new clnCadastro();
            cadastro.nome = txtNome;

```
        if (radioButtonAtivo.Checked == true)
        {
            cadastro.ativo = 1;
        }

        else if (radioButtonInativo.Checked == true) 
        {
            cadastro.ativo = 0;
        }
```

public void PreencherAtivo() // para usar no modificar, com comboBox
        {
            clnCadastro cadastro= new clnCadastro ();
            comboBoxAtivo.DataSource = cadastro.PreencherAtivo().Tables[0];
            comboBoxAtivo.ValueMember = "cod_Ativo";
            comboBoxAtivo.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
            comboBoxAtivo.SelectedIndex = -1; // para ficar em branco antes
//de selecionar

//ou modificar com radioButton
 clnCadastro cadastro= new clnCadastro ();
OracleDataReader drDados;
string nome = cadastro.nome;
drDados = cadastro.PreencherAtivoComReader(nome); 
   if (drDados.Read())
            {
                if (drDados["descricao"].toString() == "ATIVO")
                {
                    radioButtonAtivo.Checked = true;
                }

```
            else if (drDados["descricao"].toString() == "INATIVO")
            {
                radioButtonInativo.Checked = true;
            }




    }
```

Banco:

create table Mesa
(
  cod number(5),
  nome VARCHAR2(20)not null,
  Ativo number(1)not null,
  constraint PK_cod_Mesa PRIMARY KEY(cod)
contraint fk_cod_ativo foreign key (Ativo) references T_Ativo(cod_Ativo )
);

create table T_Ativo
(
cod_Ativo number (1),
Descricao char(7),

constraint  PK_cod_Ativo PRIMARY KEY(Ativo)
);

insert into T_ativo values(1,'ATIVO');
insert  into T_ativo values(0,'INATIVO');

entao vc salvara 0 para inativo e 1 para ativo no banco
e no modificar ele te retornara os textos ao invés dos numeros

ativo
inativo

espero ter ajudado